# Reproducing a Choropleth Map by using plotly package in R

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

```
library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv")
df$hover <- with(df, paste(state, '<br>', "Beef", beef, "Dairy", dairy, "<br>",
                           "Fruits", total.fruits, "Veggies", total.veggies,
                           "<br>", "Wheat", wheat, "Corn", corn))
# give state boundaries a white border
l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
# specify some map projection/options
g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

p <- plot_geo(df, locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~total.exports, text = ~hover, locations = ~code,
    color = ~total.exports, colors = 'Purples'
  ) %>%
  colorbar(title = "Millions USD") %>%
  layout(
    title = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)',
    geo = g
  )

p
```

The above code is from [plotly website](https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/) and the plot produced should be as follows:

[image]
However, the plot I generated by using the code is as follows:

[image]

What happens? Do I need to install some other packages to reproduce the correct plot?

Comment: This works fine for me using `plotly_4.5.6` - Which version are you using ?

Comment: Hi Steven, I am using exactly the same version as yours.

Comment: Try to clear your workspace and perhaps restart your session then try again and see if it works.

Comment: I have the same issue, if I open the javascript console I see the errors: `Failed to load resource: Unable to init SSL Context:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this too. If you open the javascript console you can see an error:

```
   Failed to load resource: Unable to init SSL Context:
```

while it is trying to open this file:

```
 "https://cdn.plot.ly/world_110m.json"
```

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

#### Cause:

I believe this is because the non-professional Version of R-Studio does not support **https** by design, so there is probably no work around except wrapping it as markdown and viewing it in a browser as I describe below.

#### Workaround:

If you package it in R-markdown (put your code between the following lines):

````
```{r} 

 (your code here)

```
````

and then save it as an `.Rmd` file) and knit it. Then it will still not work in the R-Studio preview-browser, and but it does if you use the "Open in Browser" function and open it in Chrome (for example).

Or buy the professional version :).

Comment: Thank you for all the explanation! The original code did work in Rstudio Server Prof in my office. Knitting it in R-markdown is a nice solution for free Rstudio.