# Load image into R for use in plotly graph - works with one URL, not another URL

Tags: r, amazon-s3, plotly

I am working on a graph that plots NBA logos on a graph. Here are two different links to the logo of a specific team - https://s3.amazonaws.com/msfsportsdatafeeds/NBALogos/hawkslogobetter.png - and - https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/24/Atlanta_Hawks_logo.svg/400px-Atlanta_Hawks_logo.svg.png.

Here is a summary of my code for the plot:

```
mydf <- data.frame(my_x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), my_y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

images.list <- list()
for(i in 1:6) {


this.list <- list(source = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/24/Atlanta_Hawks_logo.svg/400px-Atlanta_Hawks_logo.svg.png',
                    # source = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/msfsportsdatafeeds/NBALogos/hawkslogobetter.png',
                    xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                    x = mydf$my_x[i],
                    y = mydf$my_y[i],
                    sizex = 1, sizey = 1,
                    opacity = 1, layer = 'above')  
  images.list[[length(images.list)+1]] <- this.list
}

plot_ly(mydf) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~my_x, y = ~my_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(size = 1)) %>%
  layout(
    margin = list(b = 60, l = 80),
    images = images.list
  )
```

When I use the upload.wikimedia.org logo, the logos plot, but when I use the logo that I saved in an S3 bucket, the logos do not plot. I can't control if the wikimedia.org logo URLs will ever change, however I am in control of my own S3 bucket, so I'd prefer to use the s3 images for this.

Does anybody have any idea why the logos are not plotting with the S3 url? Thanks in advance!

EDIT - the images are the exact same. I saved the image from the wikipedia URL to my desktop, and uploaded that to my S3 bucket. When i uploaded the image, I made it public (viewable by all), which is why anybody can go to the link that i shared.

Comment: Which OS are you using? What happens if you download the plot and execute it in your browser? Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458527/reproducing-a-choropleth-map-by-using-plotly-package-in-r

Comment: I am using Mac OSX 10.13.1 High Sierra. I will try to download the plot and execute in browser and see if that works, and will also check the link. Thanks!